# Span of the union of two sets - Halmos

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\mathbb{H}$ and $\mathbb{K}$ are any two subspaces and if $\mathbb{M}$ is the subspace spanned by $\mathbb{H}$ and $\mathbb{K}$ together, them $\mathbb{M}$ is the same as the set of all vectors of the form $x+y$, with $x \in \mathbb{H}$ and $y \in \mathbb{K}$.

I understand how the *span* is defined; I just don't how a vector of $\mathbb{M}$ can be simply writen as $x+y$.

Comment: Say $\mathbb{M}=\mathbb{R}^2$, $\mathbb{H}$ is the $x$-axis, and $\mathbb{K}$ is the $y$-axis. How do you write elements of $\mathbb{M}$ as sums of elements of $\mathbb{H}$ and elements of $\mathbb{K}$?

Comment: If (a,b) is the vector from M, I consider (a,0) from H and (0,b) from K.

Comment: And if you had something like $7(3,0) -2(0,1) + 5(0,6) -\frac{1}{3}(2,0)$, which is a random element in the span of $\mathbb{H}\cup\mathbb{K}$, could you write it as a sum of something in $\mathbb{H}$ and something in $\mathbb{K}$?

Comment: Well, if it's just a linear combination, puttin' it all together, it's the same thing as (61/3, 28) = (61/3, 0) + (0, 28)

Comment: And wouldn't it be easier to note that $7(3,0) -\frac{1}{3}(2,0)$ necessarily is a vector in $\mathbb{H}$, and $-2(0,1)+5(0,6)$ is necessarily a vector in $\mathbb{K}$? And can you see how things will work for the problem at hand, for arbitrary $\mathbb{M}$, $\mathbb{H}$, and $\mathbb{K}$?

Comment: NOW, I CAN SEE IT! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $u \in \mathbb{M}$, then $u = \sum_i \alpha_i x_i$; since $x_i \in \mathbb{H} \cup \mathbb{K}$, we can separate the vectors in two groups, respectively.
Separating, we have $u = \sum_i \alpha_i x_i = \sum_{x_i \in \mathbb{H}} \alpha_i x_i + \sum_{x_i \in \mathbb{K}} \alpha_i x_i$; but, since $\mathbb{H}$ and $\mathbb{K}$ are subspaces, these two sums are simply two vector from those same subspaces. In other words, $u = \sum_i \alpha_i x_i = \sum_{x_i \in \mathbb{H}} \alpha_i x_i + \sum_{x_i \in \mathbb{K}} \alpha_i x_i = x + y$, where $x \in \mathbb{H}$ and $y \in \mathbb{K}$.

I think it's right now...